# "Document interning" in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I a lot of documents which I know will rarely change and are very similar to each other, specifically I know they have a nested field in the document that is always the same (for some of them)

```json
{
  "docid": 1
  "nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same": {
     "title": "this will always be the same" 
     "desc": "this will always be the same, too" 
 }
}
{
  "docid": 2
  "nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same": {
     "title": "this will always be the same" 
     "desc": "this will always be the same, too" 
 }
}
```

I don't want to store the same document over and over again, instead I want Mongo to "intern" this field, i.e only store it once and the rest will only store pointers to it.

Something like:

```json
{
  "docid": 1
  "nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same": {
     "title": "this will always be the same" 
     "desc": "this will always be the same, too" 
 }
}
{
  "docid": 2
  "nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same": <pointer to doc1.nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same>
}
```

Now, of course, I can take out this nested field into a different document and then have Mongo reference its _id field, but I am not looking for app-side solution, because this collection is being accessed via multiple workers and I don't have all the documents that have the same nested_field_that_will_always_be_the_same at any given moment.

Instead, I want a solution provided by Mongo to only store this field once for every instance it is unique.

How can I do that?

I am using Pymongo.

Comment: You could consider creating a view that contains `$lookup` logic to 'populate' the document wen only a pointer is stored. The client app would then query that view and wouldn't have to know anything about the work being done to build the documents.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting challenge - I don't think a "pure" mongo solution is possible - you'll still have to modify your app code at insertion time. Quite interested to see if anyone does come up with a pure solution

What I'd probably do is add a unique index on the nested document with a `partialFilterExpression`, the index ensures you can quickly find the ID of the matching document, and the `unique` enforces this strictly.

Something like this (I shortened your field to `nested` for brevity):

```
collection.createIndex(
   { nested: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { nested: { $type: "object" } } }
);
```

Then for my inserts, I'd do the following (pseudo code)

```
try {
  found = collection.findOne({ nested }, { projection: { _id: 1 } })
  if (found) {
    collection.insert({ docId, nested: found._id })
  }
  else {
    collection.insert({ docId, nested })
  }
}
catch (e) {
  // test for E11000 and retry
}
```